# NSFileManager creating directory error 518 NSFileWriteUnsupportedSchemeError

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsfilemanager

I was trying to create a directory

```
NSError*error=nil;

NSString* BIDirectory=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BI"];
BOOL isDir,flag=YES;
    //if the directory doesn't exist create it.
if(!([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:BIDirectory isDirectory:&isDir]&& isDir))     
    flag=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BIDirectory] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```

i got the following error

```
enter code hereError Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=518 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 518.)" UserInfo=0x197190 {NSURL=/var/mobile/Applications/55793654-6CDB-4B07-8FBF-553DC37D583D/Library/Caches/BI}
```

maybe the url is wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Instead of

```
    [NSURL URLWithString:BIDirectory]
```

please use

```
    [NSURL fileURLWithPath:BIDirectory]
```

its wrong to use URLWithString:BIDirectory on local files

Comment: Good call! Spent a few minutes and couldn't figure out what's the problem

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. I spent quite a few hours on this today before finding this answer. Was passing my tests, but not on device.