# Error when downloading from Firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get basic upload/download working with the new Firebase storage. Uploading worked fine but I am unable to download the file to the device. Can someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

```
func downloadAudio() {

let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

let pathReference = storageRef.child("testAudio/audio_test.m4a")

let localURL = getDocumentsDirectory().URLByAppendingPathComponent("audio_test2.m4a")

let downloadTask = pathReference.writeToFile(localURL) { (URL, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {

    print("ERROR - ", error.debugDescription)
  } else {
    print("SUCCESS - ", URL)
  }
 }
}
```

**PRINTS:**

ERROR -  Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={ResponseErrorDomain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, object=testAudio/audio_test.m4a, NSURL=/Users/Ben/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/02AF50F2-E9BE-4EED-A3BE-485D63264731/data/Containers/Data/Application/31BDED56-0135-4E70-943E-F897080768D6/Documents/, bucket=mydevslopesapp.appspot.com, ResponseErrorCode=518, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a storage error, it's actually an issue with the file you're attempting to write to.

Looks like `URLByAppengingString` should be `fileURLWithPath` to get a file system URL (per [NSFileManager creating directory error 518 NSFileWriteUnsupportedSchemeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744316/nsfilemanager-creating-directory-error-518-nsfilewriteunsupportedschemeerror)).

Long term we need to fish this out and serve it as a "see relevant error" rather than "read network response."

Comment: ahhh worked perfectly, thanks! If you're part of the Firebase team, it could be helpful to include this in the docs :) (for those of us who aren't too experienced)

Comment: In this example it currently uses "NSURL(String:" https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_to_a_local_file

Comment: That will work because it has the `file://` scheme that identifies it as a local file, the example above doesn't create a file URL it simply creates a URL (with no scheme). `fileURLWithPath` is just shorthand for creating an NSURL with a `file://` scheme (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097404/what-is-difference-between-urlwithstring-and-fileurlwithpath-of-nsurl)