# Images not downloading from Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download an image from the new Firebase Storage to a local file. To do this I use the example Firebase provides [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_to_a_local_file). This is my code:

```
func getTumbnails(imageName: String) {
    // Create a reference to the file you want to download
    let tumbnailRef = storageRef.child("tumbs/\(imageName)")
    // Create local filesystem URL
    let localURL: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "file:///local/tumbnails/\(imageName)")

    // Download to the local filesystem
    let downloadTask = tumbnailRef.writeToFile(localURL) { (URL, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: URL!)
            self.data = data!
            print(data)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call the function `getTumbnails("image")` I get the following error printed to the console:

**Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={object=tumbs/Sunset.png, bucket=********.appspot.com, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response., ResponseErrorDomain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, NSFilePath=/local/tumbnails, NSUnderlyingError=0x137f629c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}, ResponseErrorCode=513})**

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470266/error-when-downloading-from-firebase-storage) question here on stackoverflow, but that is a different error (Response code 518 while I have 513), and since I directly use the sample code, this should just work.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you're getting an `NSPOSIXErrorDomain` error indicating that you don't have permission to write to the file `file:///local/tumbnails/\(imageName)`, presumably because that directory (`/local`) doesn't exist and even if it does, you don't have permission to write to it.

I'd take a look at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for a list of directories you can write to--you should probably be using `/Documents` or `/tmp` for this.

Comment: Thank you! However, this works on the simulator, but not on an actual device.

Comment: It's possible that the App Sandbox on the simulator runs differently than on the device--what issue are you getting on the device? It's also likely that you're running with different permissions on the device and won't be able to write to `/Documents` (you might have to write to your user directory or just `/tmp`)

Comment: Is the error the same when you try to write to `/tmp`? Is the device jailbroken?

Comment: Yes, its the same error, and my device is not jailbroken

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your might not have declared your `storageRef` properly(ie your bucket is called `bucket=yourbucket.appspot.com`), or possibly you added `Firebase/Storage` to your `workspace` but did not update the `Google-info.plist`. Perhaps you could show more of your code?

Update: 
you can try

```
let localURL: NSURL! = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(string: "file:///local/tumbnails/\(imageName)")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have everything setup properly. I changed it to `yourbucket.appspot.com` for security reasons, as I don't have any rules yet.

Comment: perhaps you can try `let localURL: NSURL! = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(string: "file:///local/tumbnails/\(imageName)")`

Comment: It's not a Firebase Storage issue, the error (confusingly) is an `NSPOSIXErrorDomain`, meaning that the issue is coming from the file system not letting the developer write to that location.

Comment: exactly. I was looking around and one of the fix seems to be `.fileURLWithPath`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's App Transport Security of iOS 9, add this code to your `info.plist` and check again

```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
          <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: No, ATS isn't necessary since Firebase Storage uses the appropriate SSL ciphers.