# Firebase Storage download to local file error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download the image `f5bd8360.jpeg` from my Firebase Storage.
When I download this image to memory using `dataWithMaxSize:completion`, I'm able to download it.

My problem comes when I try to download the image to a local file using the `writeToFile:` instance method.
 I'm getting the following error:

```
Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown
error occurred, please check the server response."
UserInfo={object=images/f5bd8360.jpeg,
bucket=fir-test-3d9a6.appspot.com, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown
error occurred, please check the server response.,
ResponseErrorDomain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, NSFilePath=/Documents/images,
NSUnderlyingError=0x1700562c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
"Operation not permitted"}, ResponseErrorCode=513}"
```

Here is a snippet of my Swift code:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // Get a reference to the storage service, using the default Firebase App
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()

        // Get reference to the image on Firebase Storage
        let imageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://fir-test-3d9a6.appspot.com/images/f5bd8360.jpeg")

        // Create local filesystem URL
        let localURL: URL! = URL(string: "file:///Documents/images/f5bd8360.jpeg")

        // Download to the local filesystem
        let downloadTask = imageRef.write(toFile: localURL) { (URL, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Uh-oh, an error occurred!")
                print(error)
            } else {
                print("Local file URL is returned")
            }
        }
    }
```

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539785/images-not-downloading-from-firebase-storage) with the same error I'm getting but it was never answered in full. I think the proposal is right. I don't have permissions to write in the file. However, I don't know how gain permissions. Any ideas?

Comment: As per the other answer, it's likely that you don't have permission to write to `file:///Documents/images/f5bd8360.jpeg`. It's likely that you have permission to write to `/Documents`, but it's possible that `/Documents/images` doesn't exist, and isn't created automatically, thus it would fail since the file can't be written. Make sure you've got all the correct directories to write to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images not downloading from Firebase Storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539785/images-not-downloading-from-firebase-storage)

Comment: Then, how can I create a directory in iOS? Specifically the images directory.

Comment: Sorry, I tried running my code with a new localURL to "file:///Documents/f5bd8360.jpeg" but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that at the moment when you write this line:

```
let downloadTask = imageRef.write(toFile: localURL) { (URL, error) -> Void in
etc.
```

you don't yet have permission to write to that (`localURL`) location. To *get* the permission you need to write the following code before trying to write anything to `localURL`

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let localURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("filename")
```

By doing it you will write the file into the following path on your device (if you are testing on the real device):
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXXXetc.etc./Documents/filename

If you are testing on the simulator, the path will obviously be somewhere on the computer.

Comment: I have my downloadTask already set up as you advise. However, I get the warning - 

 Initialization of immutable value 'downloadTask' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

It is in a func which downloads a plist from Firebase, and that works fine. So I wonder why this warning?

Comment: This totally normal. What you see is a compiler warning basically saying that your variable is created but not used again. You can replace downloadTask with the underscore. Bear in mind that at some point you actually may need to use downloadTask. E.g. you may want to observe the download status (success/failure) or download progress etc.